# How to increase cloud composer 2 worker storage limit beyond 10GB when using KubernetesPodOperator?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I have configured cloud composer 2 [using terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/composer_environment) with the following configuration:

```
workloads_config {
      worker {
        cpu        = 2
        memory_gb  = 6
        storage_gb = 10
        min_count  = 1
        max_count  = 4
      }
    }
```

I cannot set `storage_gb` higher than 10, either in terraform or in the GCP console. In terraform, I get an error saying I can't set the value above 10GB. In the console, it's not possible to enter a value greater than 10.

I have one job using the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/use-kubernetes-pod-operator) which is failing because it hits the disk limit.

I can see the pod was evicted with the following error:

> Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers 10239Mi.

The job worked OK on Composer 1 and I don't recall having to configure the storage limit there but Composer 1 has a lot of differences in how the environment is setup.

I have not been able to find docs on how to increase this limit in Composer 2.

Things I will try next:

- try asking for more storage using pod resource requests
- see is there a way to configure the limits on the cluster outside of composer

I have not been able to find docs on how to change the 10GB limit besides [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/scale-environments) which shows how to change the storage for a worker but doesn't mention the 10GB limit.

Is there a standard way to increase the worker limit above 10GB?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#allowable_resource_ranges) as Composer 2 uses GKE Autopilot. You may refer to this [Composer 2](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-features) for details of Composer 2.

Composer workers are intended to be used for launching and/or polling for the status of work launched elsewhere. **It is not meant** to be used for local processing or for scratch computation.

If you intend to have a scratch space to work on files or do local processing, you may launch other Kubernetes pods to do so and then use `KubernetesPodOperator` or you may also try `GKEPodOperator` since the `KubernetesPodOperator` didn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks, @scott-b. I was a bit confused about the worker configurations and if they affected the pod resource limits (they don't). I ended up using `ephemeral-storage` limits on the KubernetesPodOperator which worked e.g. `k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(limits={"ephemeral-storage": "30Gi"})`